# What does the <identifier> expected Java error mean?

Tags: java

I don't get this error? I don't see anything wrong. Could anyone help?

```
public class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "Hello!";
            System.out.println(hello);
    }
}
```

It just gives me this error

> 1 error: identifier expected

Comment: Your class has no name.

Comment: The compiler needs an identifier, i.e. name, for a class. You haven't named it.

Answer (score 2):

you need to name your class, you can name it `Main` or something.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "Hello!";
        System.out.println(hello);
    }
}
```